# Sqllite and Django shell are not in sync

Tags: django, django-models

I have deleted a table from sqllite3 shell and then when I try creating it again by running python manage.py migrate/python manage.py makemigrations table is not created and showing below error. How to re-create the table and make my db and the API is insync. I tried with the python manage.py dbsync also but not worked.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, cgkapp, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying cgkapp.0002_delete_questions...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: cgkapp_questions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 246, in database_forwa
rds
    schema_editor.delete_model(model)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 287, in delete_model
    super().delete_model(model)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 317, in delete_model
    "table": self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 117, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: cgkapp_questions
```

Comment: create a new migration file and add migrations that can create the table. You can comment the migrations in previous migration and add it in new file or you delete sqlite db and create a fresh one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django migrate command try to make all migrations (they hold in migrations directory) which are not done yet.

In here you have "0002_delete_questions" migration file in your migrations directory and when you run the migrate command this migration try to delete questions table from your database but this table is already deleted. So you can handle this in two way

1. Delete this migration file from migrations directory in your project
2. run this command `python manage.py migrate --fake cgkapp 0002_delete_questions` (here 'cgkapp' is your app name and '0002_delete_questions' is your migration file name)

Comment: (django20) 07:52 ~/childrenGK $ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'cgkapp':
  cgkapp/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Questions
But I don't see the table in SQLlite (django20) 07:52 ~/childrenGK $ python manage.py dbshell

sqlite> .tables
auth_group                  auth_user_user_permissions
auth_group_permissions      django_admin_log          
auth_permission             django_content_type       
auth_user                   django_migrations         
auth_user_groups            django_session

Comment: did you run python manage.py migrate command after initial migrations? And can you post "django_migrations" table records because these table holds the done migrations do you see initial migration in this table?

Comment: I thought django_migrations might have some entries so I dropped that table :-). Now I don't know how to solve it..  Its giving big errors like below  File "/home/shrivatsa555/.virtualenvs/django20/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 301, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "django_content_type" already exists

Comment: I have only 0001_initial.py in my migrations folder and in the models.py class Questions(models.Model):
    Question_Number = models.AutoField(primary_key = True),
    Question_Text = models.TextField(max_length = 1000),
    Option1 = models.TextField(max_length=500),
    Option2 = models.TextField(max_length=500),
    Option3 = models.TextField(max_length=500),
    Option4 = models.TextField(max_length=500),
    Answer = models.TextField(max_length=500),
    Difficulty_Level = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_number])

Comment: At last solved the issue with python manage.py migrate --fake-initial.. and your suggestion helped me.